# Как вывести результат в метку?

Tags: windows, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток, у меня такой вопрос: есть  textbox на форме кнопка button и label.
По кнопке button при нажатии должно производится вычисление какого нибудь выражения, (допустим 2*2)  и выводиться результат в метку. Я помню, как это сделать по делфи, а на с++ только перешел.

**Добавлено.**

```
private:System::Void button1_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    double a, b, c, p, s;
    label6->Text = "";
    label7->Text = "";
    a = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
    b = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
    c = Convert::ToDouble(textBox3->Text);
    if ((a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (c + b) > a) {
        p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        s = fsqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
        textBox4->Text = s.ToString("N");
        textBox5->Text = p.ToString("N");
    }
}
```

Вот типа такого, только я хочу, чтоб выводилось в одну метку, а вводилось в texbox.  Программа Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: забыл добавить, что как  это сделать в форматном выводе?

Comment: Никаких кнопок, форм и меток в языке C++ и его стандартной библиотеке не существует. Если имеется в виду те или иные инструменты для построения GUI (WinAPI, MFC, Windows Forms, wxWidgets, Qt и еще много других) - укажите конкретнее, иначе сложно будет Вам помочь.

Comment: как так? а в  visual studio 2008? т

Comment: да я извиняюсь, у меня visual studio мне бы конструкцию вывода показать(

Comment: Я что-то не понял, пользователи с репутацией->0 не могут оставлять комментарии? @Хэшкод, ответьте пожалуйста. Это явно не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: Я не знаю, я нажал  ответить,оно появилось, я тоже удивился

Comment: ребят, хватит офтопить, ответьте на вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: @Doc_Freemen **Да вам же уже сказали, что нужно уточнить вопрос.** Я, например, могу вспомнить как минимум несколько UI платформ, где названия контролов имеют схожие значения и для каждой из них решения будут разные. У вас наверняка уже есть какой-то код - так выложите его.

Comment: Для начала стоит научиться пользоваться MSDN.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике нажатия кнопки надо

1. считать текст выражения,
2. вычислить его значение,
3. вывести результат.

Если предположить (из вопроса это неясно), что для каждого операнда есть свое поле ввода, а  для результата - свое, то мы имеем такой код

```
double a = Convert::ToDouble(textboxA->Text);
double b = Convert::ToDouble(textboxB->Text);
double c = a * b;

labelC->Text = c.toString();
```

Comment: Ну что все этому Convert'у привязались? Double.Parse же есть.